# HSPICE code to cut off supply voltage of a subcircuit

Tags: voltage, cmos, spice

I am trying to cut off the supply voltage "Vcontrol" of a subblock "circuit" for a very short time using a pmos, a nmos transitor and a voltage source. The Hspice code is as follows:

```
Vpulse Pulse 0 PWL (0.0n 0 0.1n 1 2n 1 2.1n 0)
M1 Vcontrol Pulse VSS! VSS! NMOS L=1u W=6u
M2 Vcontrol Pulse VDD! VDD! PMOS L=1u W=6u
Xcircuit Nin1 Nin2 Nin3 Vcontrol VDD! circuit
```

Using this code, I cannot pull the voltage level inside the circuit completely to 0, it looks rather like an RC discharge curve until a certain level. It does not drop below it that level, even when I increase the pulse width.
Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong or knows a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see any connection to the 0 node. How are VSS! and VDD! generated? Is VSS! equal to ground (node 0) or is it a negative supply voltage?

Comment: Hi, These are the Statements for VSS! and VDD!: VSS! VSS! 0 DC 0 and VDD! VDD! 0 DC 1

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the transistors don't have zero on-resistance (it depends on whatever your model is) so you get the RC (the on-resistance of the transistor and the capacitive load of the subcircuit) discharge and non-zero final output.

If this is an actual design, you're going to have to deal with it.  If you have a power mosfet and the current of the subcircuit is not too high you can put a pass device you turn all at the same time you switch the supply.  (This is essentially using a voltage regulator with shutdown to drive your subcircuit).  You could also use a bigger (larger W/L) device.  Typically mosfets that need to deal with large currents are very large.  Your devices are quite small as it is.  Try something more like a mm or two for W.

If this, instead, is simply for a simulation testbench, you should use an ideal switch instead of a transistor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I used stronger transistors and also tried to insert a pass gate to the VControl signal but unfortunately neither of them works. I still get similar results as before. :( The result is equivalent as when I feed the inverted Pulse signal directly to the subcircuit.